# Page of PDF written in footer

Tags: c#, pdf, numbers

Does anyone an idea how acrobat reader knows the page I am currently viewing? 
For example - I have a PDF file which contains page numbers in footer in format - 1/A or 1/1 - divided into chapters, and acrobat knows that this is number of page - it doesnt write only total number of pages from beggining to this current page.

I am writing C# apps, WinForms, where I need to get number of page - in the same way as acrobat does.
I am converting each page into text with pdfLibView lib, but then,  I need look at last page and use complex algorithms to find out which string in footer is page number - it can contain any other informations.

So any idea, how to get page number in format as it is written on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your document uses page labels feature defined in PDF specification.

8.3.1 Page Labels says:

> In addition, a document may optionally define page labels (PDF 1.3) to
> identify each page visually on the screen or in print. Page labels and
> page indices need not coincide: the indices are fixed, running
> consecutively through the document starting from 0 for the first page,
> but the labels can be specified in any way that is appropriate for the
> particular document. For example, if the document begins with 12 pages
> of front matter numbered in roman numerals and the remainder of the
> document is numbered in arabic, the first page would have a page index
> of 0 and a page label of i, the twelfth page would have index 11 and
> label xii, and the thirteenth page would have index 12 and label 1.

You might try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) if you want to access page labels information in an existing document (disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library).

Here is a sample for how to [add Page Labels to PDF document](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Pages%20and%20Navigation/PageLabels). This sample doesn't show how to access existing labels but might give some clues for a start.